# How to say "heard back from university"

Tags: translation

Let's say, I applied to some universities, and haven't heard back from one of them. Should I say (for example, to a friend)

> Ich habe von einem Platz noch nicht zurückgehört.  ?

Is it right to use Platz here, as in the English "place"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Verb *zurückgehört* gibt es meines Wissens nicht. Und *Platz* alleine ist mißverständlich, da es gemeinhin entweder in der Bedeutung "piazza" verwendet wird, oder in der Bedeutung "space" (*Ich habe nicht genug Platz.*)

Man kann sagen:

> Ich habe bezüglich eines Studienplatzes noch nichts (Neues) gehört.
>
> Ich habe noch von keiner Uni eine Rückmeldung/Antwort erhalten.

Comment: Sounds good, I like "Studienplatz" here, and also your second example.

Answer (score -1):

It is wrong to use such offensive words in that context. It would really mean "I havent heard back from your place", which is very wrong. You wouldnt say either in any conversation, if english or german, why even write a univerisity such a note? By all means the least you could do is "Wenn sie mir bitte Benachrichtigen, ob eine Stelle frei ist." What would mean "If you could please respind, if there is still a place availible."

Comment: You're misunderstanding my question.. I want to say that sentence to a friend, not to the university.